# Interesting Problem - Computing CDF

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

A rv X is an exponential distribution with parameter 1 and Y is a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

X and Y are independent.

Define Z = min {X, Y}. Compute the CDF of Z ?

I really have no idea about this question.

My thought is that you need to use integration but how exactly ?

Can any experts shed some light on this one ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed independent?

Comment: @StefanHansen: Sorry and yes they are :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we knew the *joint* distribution of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, we could solve the problem. With *no* such information, we cannot.

We will make the simplest assumption, that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*. It is likely that we are meant to assume independence, and that the condition was inadvertently left out.

We will find the cdf $F_Z(z)$ of $Z$, that is, the probability that $Z\le z$.  This is clearly $0$ if $z\lt 0$. Assume now that $z\ge 0$.

We have $\min(X,Y)\gt z$ if and only if $X\gt z$ **and** $Y\gt z$. Suppose first that $0\le z\le 1$. Then $\Pr(X\gt z)=e^{-z}$ and $\Pr(Y\gt z)=1-z$, so for $0\le z\le 1$ we have $\Pr(Z\gt z)=e^{-z}(1-z)$, and therefore $F_Z(z)=1-e^{-z}(1-z)$.

If $z\gt 1$, then $\Pr(Z\le z)=1$, so $F_Z(z)=1$.

Comment: Why do you find the product of 2 probability, namely, e^(-z)(1-z) ?

Comment: The probability that the minimum is greater than $z$ is the probability that $X\gt z$ **and** $Y\gt z$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, this is $\Pr(X\gt z)\Pr(Y\gt z)$. In this case, that ives $e^{-z}(1-z)$. So to sum up, it is because when $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But if I use p(X<z) = 1-e^(-z) and p(Y<z) = z and then find the product of these 2, which is z-ze^(-z). But that's different from your answer ? Why ?

Comment: This gives the probability that **both** are $\lt z$, which is not the probability that the min is $\lt z$. The min can be $\lt z$ with one small and the other big. We do have that your proposed product is the probability that the **max** is $\lt z$.